# Switch methods in object using protoype

Tags: javascript, overriding, prototype

I have a piece of code that switches the processing used on an object, a, outside of a function test. The function, test, uses properties of a and a.b and a.c:

```
let a;
let fB = {method: function(o){o.b.count++;return o.b.value}};
let fC = {method: function(o){o.c.count++;return o.c.value}};
a = new class A {value='Method:'; b={value:'B',count:0}; c={value:'C',count:0}};
function test (a,f) {
    console.log(a.value+f.method(a));
}
test(a,fB); // method:B
test(a,fC); // method:C
console.log('Counts:',a.b.count,a.c.count) // Counts: 1 1
```

I want to write it in a more OO way, something like :

```
function test (a) {
    console.log(a.value+a.method());
}
class B {
    constructor(){this.val='B';this.count=0}
    method (){this.count++;return this.val}
}
class C {
    constructor(){this.val='C';this.count=0}
    method (){this.count++;return this.val}
}
class A {
    value='Method:';
}

a = new A();
Object.setPrototypeOf(a,new B());
test(a); // method:B
Object.setPrototypeOf(a,new C());
test(a); // method:C
console.log('Counts:',a.b.count,a.c.count) // a.b is undefined
```

The best I could come up with was :

```
class B {
    constructor(){this.value='B';this.count=0}
    method (){this.count++;return this.value}
}
class C {
    constructor(){this.value='C';this.count=0}
    method (){this.count++;return this.value}
}
class A {
    value='Method:';
    b=new B();
    c=new C();
    x=this.b;

    switchToB(){this.x = this.b}
    switchToC(){this.x = this.c}
    method(){return this.x.method()}
}

a = new A();

function test (a) {
    console.log(a.value+a.method());
}
test(a); // method:B
a.switchToC();
test(a); // method:C
console.log('Counts:',a.b.count,a.c.count) // Counts: 1 1
```

I don't much like this, nor an alternative :

```
class B {
    constructor(a){this.value=a.value;this.val='B';this.count=0}
    method (){this.count++;return this.val}
}
class C {
    constructor(a){this.value=a.value;this.val='C';this.count=0}
    method (){this.count++;return this.val}
}
class A {
    value='Method:';
    b=new BB(this);
    c=new CC(this);
}

a = new A();
test(a.b); // method:B
test(a.c); // method:C
console.log('Counts:',a.b.count,a.c.count) // Counts: 1 1
```

Is there a better way to do this in JS ?

Comment: For `B` and `C` classes, you can maybe create a base class, and make `B` and `C` extend that class. Something like `class B extends BaseLetter`, for example. I am suggesting this just because you are basically repeating the same code in classes `B` and `C`.

Comment: Seems odd you would switch the prototype of an object. What exact problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What is wrong with the code in the block labeled with: "I want to write it in a more OO way, something like :"

Comment: *"better"*: define what you mean with better? This question would be more useful if there were clear requirements. I note that in the different snippets you change the number of parameters in `test`, insert a new method `switchTo`, ...etc. It is not clear what is acceptable to you and what is not.

Comment: What's wrong with the original? Why do you want to try and force something created in a more or less functional matter into a OOP box?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Better in my view is combination of efficiency, readability and less duplication. The 3rd snippet duplicates the B and C methods in A with pass through method rather than calling them directly. The 4th snippet duplicates the properties of A in B and C rather than using them directly. The 2nd snippet does not maintain the results of using the B and C methods.

Comment: So it seems the first snippet is the only one that fulfills your needs. Apparently you want nothing to be changed. So then don't.

Comment: I am new to JS and OOP. The pattern for doing what I need in snippet 1 seems a bit obscure. My first attempts at reproducing the results usjng different patterns are no better or do not work. I tried to encapsulate the requirements of the code without unnecessary details in the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first OO attempt that you provided, there are these observations:

- No `b` or `c` properties are created on `a`, yet the testing code needs them.
- Also the switching mechanism should work with a reference to these `b` and `c` properties
- `B` and `C` are look-alikes so that could be generalised to one `Counter` class whose constructor takes an argument that distinguishes them (determining the `value` property).
- We could also think of a more lazy initialisation, where a counter object is only created when `a` switches to it.
- There seems to be a relationship between the name "b" and the output "B". Similar between "c" and "C". So one could be derived from the other.

This leads to the following implementation:

```js
class Counter {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value.toUpperCase();
        this.count = 0;
    }
    method() {
        this.count++;
        return this.value;
    }
}

class A {
    constructor() {
        this.value = 'Method:'; 
    }
    activateCounter(name) {
        // Create a new counter if not used before
        this[name] ??= new Counter(name);
        // Redirect the method to use this counter's method
        this.method = () => this[name].method();
    }
}

function test(a) {
    console.log(a.value + a.method());
}

let a = new A();
a.activateCounter("b");
test(a); // method:B
a.activateCounter("c");
test(a); // method:C
console.log('Counts:', a.b.count, a.c.count) // Counts: 1 1
```

Here `a.method()` should only be called *after* a counter was activated with a call of `a.activateCounter`. This is because the latter will (re)define the `method` method on a.

Comment: Many thanks. i) b or c properties inherited from prototype but not b and c so does not work for my purpose because result needed. iii) methods of B and C substantially different (B=descendants, C=Ancestors in family tree code). Apologies for my misleading precis code snippets.

Comment: I don't understand anything you wrote here. Ancestors? Family tree? There is nothing about that in your question.